# Qual a diferença entre os seletores "element element" e "element > element"?

Tags: css, css-seletores

Estava olhando o código do [Twitter Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L2411), e encontrei este CSS:

```css
.table-condensed > tfoot > tr > td {
  /* ... */
}
```

Em sentido de funcionamento, qual seria a diferença de colocar apenas um espaço entre os elementos, e colocar o `>`?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

### `element element { ...`

O espaço entre dois elementos do CSS é o **seletor de descendente**.
Descendente é qualquer elemento que se encontra declarado dentro de outro.

### `element > element { ...`

O `>` entre dois elementos do css é o **seletor de filho**.
Filho também é descendente, mas é o "descendente direto" especificamente. Ou seja, está diretamente inserido no elemento anterior.

### Na prática:

Quando você escreve `div span { ... }`, você está dizendo qualquer `span` descendente (dentro) do `div`, e atuando no `span` nos dois casos abaixo:

```html
<div><span> bla bla </span></div>
<div><a><span> bla bla </span></a></div>
```

Agora, quando usa `div > span { ... }`, vai ter efeito em apenas filhos do `div`, como este:

```html
<div><span> bla bla </span></div>
```

Os atributos **não vão ser aplicados** em outros níveis de descendência, como neste caso:

```html
<div><a><span> bla bla </span></a></div>
```

Motivo: o `<span>` neste último caso é "neto" do `<div>`, ou seja, é descendente mas não é filho, pois o filho é o `<a>`.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```css
div span {
  text-decoration: underline
}

div>span {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div>
  Div 1
  <span> Span 1 </span>
</div>
<div>
  <a>
    Div 2
    <span> Span 2 </span>
  </a>
</div>
<div>
  <a>
    Div 3
    <span> Span 3 </span>
  </a>
  <span> Span 4 </span>
</div>

<br>Notar que o sublinhado ficou em todos os spans, mas o vermelho somente quando o span é filho (descendente de primeiro nível) do div
```