# Como criar uma caixa com dois textos separados

Tags: css, estilo-de-codificação, xhtml

Olá,

Sou iniciante de XHTML e peço que me falem deste código e não do html5.

Quero fazer um cabeçalho mas não estou a conseguir. O objetivo é que o primeiro texto fique mais em cima que o primeiro. Vejam a imagem do exemplo sf.

Estou em dúvida tanto no xhtml como no css. A caixa é para colocar como primeiro elemento do site.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um pequeno exemplo de como conseguir isso, utilizando apenas CSS.

Existe mais uma infinidade de outras formas de conseguir o mesmo resultado.

HTML:

```
<div class="FUNDO">
    <span class="CIMA">Título do site</span>
    <span class="BAIXO">Outro texto</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.FUNDO {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    font: normal 30px sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 220px;
}
.CIMA {
    position: absolute;
    left: 25px;
    top: 25px;
}
.BAIXO {
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    bottom: 25px;
}
```

O exemplo pode ser testado ao vivo [nesse Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MNnp6/1/).

Comment: Carlosraelgn agradeço imenso a sua ajuda. 5 estrelas. Muito obrigado, mesmo. Só fiquei com uma dúvida: porquê que não podemos usar div id e p class? O div id não é unico?

Comment: @David pode-se utilizar o `id`, sim, e em vez de `span`, `p`. Foi só um exemplo :)

Answer (score 5):

Como já respondido pelo [@carlosrafaelgn](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/7998/), existem várias maneiras de se fazer o que você pretende.

Usei a mesma técnica proposta por ele, e fiz apenas algumas alterações estruturais. Originalmente ia por como *comment* na resposta já existente, mas ia ficar ilegível, então acabei postando em separado. De qualquer forma, a resposta original já ganhou meu +1.

A diferença basicamente é o uso de tags semânticas no lugar dos `div`s, para preservar a estrutura lógica da página independentemente do CSS.

No caso, usei o `<p>` para mero texto informativo na segunda linha de texto, mas você pode usar `<h2>` se for um subtítulo, por exemplo. O importante é usar a tag que melhor identifica o sentido do conteúdo que lá está.

HTML:

```
<div id="cab">
   <h1>Título do site</h1>
   <p>Outro texto</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#cab    { position: relative;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          height: 200px; }

#cab h1 { position: absolute;
          top: 25px;
          left: 25px; }

#cab p  { position: absolute;
          bottom: 25px;
          right: 25px; }
```

> Como usamos tags diferentes para as duas linhas, ficou desnecessário especificar classes, e para isso bastou usar o [seletor de descendente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2256/).

Veja em funcionamento no **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bacco/g72z3/)**.

Comment: Sim, concordo contigo! É melhor não utilizar `span`s genéricos, mas elementos com significados mais específicos :) Mas se fosse para utilizar `p`, teria que configurar o `text-align`, para `right` ;)

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn chegou a ver o fiddle? Testei no Opera/Presto, Chrome, IE 11, IE 6 (!), e FF, e todos se comportaram bem. O `<p>` com `absolute` teoricamente não fica com width 100% do parent, então funciona como esperado. Mas se achar algum browser "dissidente" neste aspecto me avise, que reviso de acordo.

Comment: Pois é! Não me atentei a isso, não! Ficou joinha, mesmo! Falha minha :(

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn grato de qualquer forma. Eu entendi sua preocupação, normalmente precisa sim, por causa do 100%. É que justo neste caso específico, a exceção acabou ajudando.

Comment: Obrigado a todos pela ajuda :) Na verdade estou a fazer um layout liquido com xhtml e portanto penso não poder usar pixeis. Em vez disso penso que tenho de usar a percentagem. Confesso que está a me dar alguma dor de cabeça.

Comment: @David creio que você não deva se preocupar tanto com isso. É muito simples usar px e % no mesmo layout, e as _media queries_ resolvem a maior parte do problema em dispositivos diferentes. Não caia na ilusão de querer que o site simplesmente "amplie inteiro" na mesma proporção, pois além das diferenças de tamanho, há as diferenças de proporção. O melhor caminho é esboçar como deve ficar nas diferentes telas, e depois decidir qual "ferramenta" vai usar em qual parte do site. Veja os sites que se comportam como você gostaria, e estude suas técnicas. Isso independe de ser (X)HTML, o CSS é igual.

Comment: @Bacco obrigado pelo conselho. Vocês são nota 1000. Estou a aprender xhtml e css. Ando de volta de um site liquido para praticar a técnica. Depois que a dominar faço um outro site exemplo gelatina. Sei que hoje existem ferramentas mais adequadas ao trabalho final do layout liquido em xhtml afinal de contas já se usa o html5 em conjunto com outras ferramentas. O meu objetivo é mais para aprender neste momento. Veja - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21302/como-criar-um-layout-liquido-com-xhtml-1-0-strict