# Pegar elemento filho de pai e filho criados dinamicamente

Tags: jquery

Tenho a seguinte questão: 
Crio dinamicamente varias id e class.

O que preciso é quando clicar na id pai o filho receba um toggle.

Super pai recebe via append as divs.

Quando eu clicar em "aperte" da 39 a filha (de 39) tem que sofrer um toggle. Quando eu clicar em "aperte" da 40 a filha (de 40) tem que sofrer um toggle, e assim por diante (terei muito disso na mesma página).

```html
<div id="superpai">
 <div id="39"> aperte 
         <div class="filha">39</div>
</div>
<div id="40"> aperte 
         <div class="filha">40</div>
</div>
<div id="41"> aperte 
         <div class="filha">41</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Qual seria solução mais simples pra isso ?
Quando eu sei o elemento pai é bem simples. Mas quando eu não sei (que é este o caso). 
Como faço ?

Qual a melhor forma ?

Comment: É isto que procuras? https://jsfiddle.net/3cytL5ga/

Comment: Exatamente isso. 
Valeu.

Answer (score 1):

O que procuras pode ser assim:

```
$(document).on('click', '#superpai > div', function() {
  $(this).find('.filha').toggle();
});
```

É bom usares classe `.filha` assim, na altura que o evento `click` acontece o jQuery procura por um elemento com essa classe, descendente do elemento clicado.

O delegador aqui é o `.on()` [já explicado aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5199/129). Ou seja, quando houver um clique na página, o jQuery procura por elementos `div` que sejam [descendente direto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2257/129) de `#superpai`.

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3cytL5ga/1/