# Verificar a quantidade de li's dentro de uma div em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde Pessoal gostaria de pegar a quantidades de `li` dentro dessa div, como posso fazer?

```
<div id="collapse305" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading375" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">      
  <div class="panel-body">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/download/1771" target="_blank">Test1</a>  
        <span class="label label-info"></span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/download/1791" target="_blank">Test2</a>  
        <span class="label label-info"></span>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/download/1796" target="_blank">Test3</a>  
         <span class="label label-info"></span>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/download/1801" target="_blank">Test4</a>  
         <span class="label label-info"></span>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/download/1827" target="_blank">Test5</a>  
         <span class="label label-info"></span>
      </li>
    </ul>      
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kg9j78s5/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma de contar depende muito do que você quer dizer com "li's dentro de uma div".

No seu caso específico, bastaria fazer `document.querySelectorAll('#collapse305 li').length`, como [sua própria resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/458993/112052) indicou.

Mas e se tivermos um HTML assim:

```html
<div id="collapse305">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul id="lista1">
            <li>Test1</li>
            <li>Test2</li>
            <li>Test3</li>
            <li>
              Test4
              <ul id="sublista1">
                  <li>Subtest4.1</li>
                  <li>Subtest4.2</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <p>blablabla</p>
        <ul id="lista2">
            <li>Test5</li>
            <li>Test6</li>
        </ul>
        <div id="outra">
            <ul id="lista3">
                <li>Test7</li>
                <li>Test8</li>
                <li>
                Test9
                  <ul id="sublista3">
                      <li>Test10</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Você quer contar todos os elementos `li`? Ou somente os do primeiro `ul`? Ou só os que não estão aninhados? Ou só os do primeiro nível?

Por exemplo, se eu fizer `document.querySelectorAll('#collapse305 > div > ul > li')`, ele só vai pegar `Test1`, `Test2`, `Test3`, `Test4`, `Test5` e `Test6`, já que o `>` [só pega elementos que são descendentes diretos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator), ou seja, `#collapse305 > div` só pega a `div` que é filha imediata do elemento cujo `id` é `collapse305` (que no caso é a `div class="panel-body"`), depois `> ul` só pega os elementos `ul` que são filhos diretos desta `div class="panel-body"` (ou seja, somente os elementos `ul` cujos id's são `lista1` e `lista2`), e por fim `> li` vai pegar somente os elementos `li` que são filhos diretos destes `ul`'s (por isso ele não pega o `Subtest4.1` e nem `Subtest4.2`, já que estes não são filhos diretos de `lista1`).

Já quando você não usa `>`, ele pega os [descendentes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) daquele elemento, independente de serem filhos diretos (ou seja, podem ser "netos", "bisnetos", etc). Veja mais sobre esses seletores [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2257/112052).

---

Isso permite várias formas diferentes de contar. Por exemplo, se remover um `>` do seletor: `document.querySelectorAll('#collapse305 div > ul > li')`.

Agora ele vai pegar qualquer `div` dentro de `collapse305`, o que quer dizer que além da `div class="panel-body"`, também será pego a `div id="outra"`, e com isso o `ul id="lista3"` também será considerado. Porém, só serão pegos os `li`'s que são filhos diretos deste `ul`, e por isso o `Test10` fica de fora. O resultado será `Test1`, `Test2`, `Test3`, `Test4`, `Test5`, `Test6`, `Test7`, `Test8` e `Test9`.

Mas se eu mudar para `document.querySelectorAll('#collapse305 > div > ul li')`, agora eu pego todos os `li`'s dentro de `lista1` e `lista2`, ou seja, `Test1`, `Test2`, `Test3`, `Test4`, `Subtest4.1`, `Subtest4.2`, `Test5` e `Test6`.

---

Claro que para casos mais simples como o seu (dentro da `div` só existe um `ul` sem `li`'s aninhados), não fará diferença. Mas dependendo de como está o HTML e do que você quer considerar na contagem, usar o seletor correto pode fazer toda a diferença.

Answer (score 1):

Fácil e prático meu amigo. Terá de usar o JavaScript.

Caso queira que a quantidade apareça no console, basta dar um `console.log`

```
const quantidadeLi = document.querySelectorAll('li').length;
console.log(quantidadeLi);
```

O atributo `length` no código está diretamente ligado ao querySelectorAll.
Se caso queira exibir na tela para o usuário, use:

```
  const quantidadeLi = document.querySelectorAll('li').length;
  document.body.innerHTML = `<p> ${quantidadeLi} </p>`
```

O `document.body.innerHTML` irá criar um parágrafo com a quantidade de `li` no corpo da página. Qualquer dúvida me avise.

Answer (score 1):

Yo!

Minha sugestão é a utilização de uma classe para seus **li**

**Ganho**: A contagem não irá depender daquela div, específica ou de nenhuma outra.

**Perda**: Talvez a classe já esteja definida, e não possa dispor de tal.

**Utilizando Jquery 3.5.1**

- Copyright JS Foundation and other contributors
- Released under the MIT license
- https://jquery.org/license

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js">
</script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test Div Count</title>
</head>
    <div id="contteiner">
        <ul>
            <li class="liTeste">Teste 1</li>
            <li class="liTeste">Teste 2</li>
            <li class="liTeste">Teste 3</li>
            <li class="liTeste">Teste 4</li>
            <li class="liTeste">Teste 5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<body>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){                                     
        alert($(".liTeste").length) //AQUI ACONTECE A CONTAGEM
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A reposta é:

```js
var qtd = document.querySelectorAll('#collapse305  li').length;
console.log('A quantidade de <li>\'s é', qtd);
```

```html
<div id="collapse305" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading375" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">      
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/download/1771" target="_blank">Test1</a>  
                <span class="label label-info"></span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/download/1791" target="_blank">Test2</a>  
                <span class="label label-info"></span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/download/1796" target="_blank">Test3</a>  
                <span class="label label-info"></span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/download/1801" target="_blank">Test4</a>  
                <span class="label label-info"></span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/download/1827" target="_blank">Test5</a>  
                <span class="label label-info"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>      
    </div>
</div>
```